# Blue Green Deployment - Pod count does not match in Blue and Green versions

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, amazon-eks, hpa, blue-green-deployment

I've implemented a Blue Green Setup for our application deployment using Harness. There is one problem which im facing, assume Green env is live and serving Traffic. HPA config for green env looks like this

Green
Min - 2; Max 20; Current -16

I'm deploying a new version of application which causes k8s to create a new Blue env with below config

Blue
Min - 2; Max - 20; current - 2

Here is the problem begins, When we do a service switch to point to Blue pods (new version, 100% switch), application faces issues as OOMKilled errors, Increase in Response time as Min 2 pods cannot handle the request in time, thus causing whole lot of problems in other microservices.

Right now, we do not have concrete solution, as We are still working on an Istio POC and Harness does not support traffic split.

How can i make replicas for the new deployment to current replicas of the old version?

i implemented blue green setup mentioned in https://developer.harness.io/docs/continuous-delivery/deploy-srv-diff-platforms/kubernetes/kubernetes-executions/create-a-kubernetes-blue-green-deployment/

Basically when deploying a new version, i'm expecting same number of pods as the current version, but k8s spins up min pods as there is no traffic to new version.

If we switch traffic to new version by pointing service to new image version, we are getting lots of alerts in terms of response time, sometimes OOMKilled error with all pods in new version, 0 pods running.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.